# OpenShift custom domain not working for internal pages

Tags: openshift

I purchased a domain (iwantmydomain) and it points to an openshift application, main page loads and status bar shows the custom domain, but when I click a post then it shows the openshift url.

www.alrazylabs.com

I tried to follow:
https://www.openshift.com/blogs/domain-names-and-ssl-in-the-openshift-web-console

Answer (score 1):

At the moment it looks like everything is working fine.  Usually if a wordpress blog's links are pointing to the wrong url (the .rhcloud.com one) it means that you did not change the url in the wordpress admin to your custom domain.